# How to: Add custom video driver to bootable mint USB?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Is there a way to modify bootable Linux Mint 14 image on USB to add the display driver?

I liked the Mint when I saw the interface first time, however, I am stuck with a video driver issue - while installing on the machine that I need to run this.  I have a way to download the driver separately.

I did some googling but didn't find relevant hits.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Murali! Please register your account on Stack Overflow, then come back here, and log in with the same account. This way you can add comments, edit your post, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

If you have regular bootable driver than there is no way ti install and save driver, you have to create a LiveUSB that is able to be persistent(able to save changes on it etc.) Download next app and follow the instructions:
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ 
Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the link, are you saying if I create bootable USB with persistence, I should be able to somehow add the new driver on a different machine and boot the target machine with it? Adding the driver to installer is a black box (and core of the issue) to me - any info or link.